# calabash-ios physical device test, app starts but crashes

Tags: ios, ruby, testing, calabash, calabash-ios

Running calabash-ios cucumber for simple iPhone app. Simulator is working perfectly. When trying on physical device, app loads, crashes, then loads again, and crashes again, on a loop.

Error message:

```
Unable to start. Make sure you've set APP_BUNDLE_PATH to a build supported by this simulator version
  Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError: Time out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError. 
   Logfile /var/folders/9s/yttj4cz93m98hqs6bfw2x8xr0000gn/T/run_loop20150522-12657-dr3m49/run_loop.out 

   2015-05-22 19:58:11 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
  Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 2.594758s; Output : /var/folders/9s/yttj4cz93m98hqs6bfw2x8xr0000gn/T/run_loop20150522-12657-dr3m49/trace.trace)
  to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException

   (Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:766:in `new_run_loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:631:in `relaunch'
```

Steps:

1. loaded app-cal on device
2. ran in command-line using:

   $ DEVICE_TARGET=udid BUNDLE_ID=com.company.app DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://ip:37265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError
```

The probably cause of this is that the device is not enabled for UIAutomation.  The device must be enabled for development.  A device is enabled for development if it appears in Xcode's Device's window (Shift + Command +2) and you must enable on-device testing manually by visiting the device's Settings.app > Developer tab.

If you have recently upgraded the iOS version we recommend that you check the UIAutomation settings again and perform a restart.  Often, after an upgrade, Xcode cannot download debugging information from the device.  Look at Xcode's Device's window.  The device must appear without any warnings.

Sometimes devices get into a bad state and Xcode cannot communicate with it.  We recommend trying to interact with the device with Apple's Instruments to clear this bad state.

All this information and more can be found on the Calabash iOS Hot Topics page.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics#6-errnoeintr-interrupted-system-call